# Exception Notifier in Rails 4 app's not sending email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, actionmailer, exception-notification

I am fighting with this issue the whole afternoon.

I used this gem:

```
gem 'exception_notification'
```

and then I put this to the `/config/environments/production.rb` file:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://www.website.com' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
  # Defaults to:
  # config.action_mailer.sendmail_settings = {
  #   location: '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
  #   arguments: '-i -t'
  # }
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  #config.action_mailer.default_options = {from: 'admin@website.com'}
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :user_name => "myemail@gmail.com",
    :password => "password",
    :authentication => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
    :email => {
      :email_prefix => "[App Error] ",
      :sender_address => %{"notifier" <myemail@gmail.com>},
      :exception_recipients => %w{error_email@gmail.com}
    }
```

But it didn't work out.

So I tried to put it to the `/config/application.rb` file:

```
...
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...
    config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
      :email => {
        :email_prefix => "[App Error] ",
        :sender_address => %{"notifier" <myemail@gmail.com>},
        :exception_recipients => %w{error_email@gmail.com}
      }
  end
end
```

How I am testing it - I put to the URL not existing ID, for example `/users/1000000`. But I don't receive any email with this error to my inbox.

Could anyone help me out with this issue?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kind of an old post, but I might have an answer. You have two configs for action_mailer in your production config:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
# and also...
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
```

Might want to remove one of them.